# How does one give the Class Object an upper bound generic?

Tags: java, generics

I have 2 interfaces and 2 classes:

```
interface MyInterface1 { ... }
interface MyInterface2 extends MyInterface1 { ... }

class MyClass1 implements MyInterface1 { ... }
class MyClass2 implements MyInterface2 { ... }
```

I want to be able to specify classes such that the `Class` Object can only be at least of type `MyInterface1` (which includes all classes that are at least of `MyInterface2`, right?). I thought it might work with `Class<? extends MyInterface1>`; however, this only allows classes that directly implement `MyInterface1` and not `MyInterface2`.

A more specific implementation follows:

```
public interface Algorithm<E extends Solution<E>> { ... }
public interface EvoAlgorithm<E extends Solution<E>> extends Algorithm<E> { ... }

public class GeneticAlgorithm<E extends Solution<E>> implements EvoAlgorithm<E> { ... }
public class TSPNNAlgorithm implements Algorithm<TSPSolution> { ... }

public enum AlgorithmType {
    //**this is where the compiler error is occuring**
    GENETIC(GeneticAlgorithm.class),

    //**no compiler error here**
    NEAREST_NEIGHBOUR(TSPNNAlgorithm.class);

    private AlgorithmType(Class<? extends Algorithm<?>> algorithmClass) { ... }
}
```

Comment: That should be correct - can you post more code?

Comment: I think I have realised why, actually; is it because the compiler doesn't know at runtime what type GeneticAlgorithm.class is?

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem and it works.

Check the below code snippet:

```
interface MyInterface1 {  }
interface MyInterface2 extends MyInterface1 {  }

class MyClass1 implements MyInterface1 {  }
class MyClass2 implements MyInterface2 {  }
public class Program1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        a(MyClass1.class);
        a(MyClass2.class);

    }

    public static void a(Class<? extends  MyInterface1> input){
        System.out.println("OK");

    }

}
```

Comment: This shows that my problem is, probably, elsewhere in my generics.